# App going to wrong Activity. While back-button goes to right one

Tags: android, android-intent

my problem is as following:

When I click a button in my ActionBar it goes to the wrong activity. While when I am on the wrong activity and press the back-button. It goes to the one it was supposed to go to.

It's supposed to go to the AddActivity when the button is pressed.

If any other code is requested, please ask.

**MapsActivity**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        initialize();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_marker:
                // User chose the "Add marker" item
                Intent addActivityIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(addActivityIntent);
            case R.id.action_logout:
                // User chose the "Uitloggen" item
                PokeMapperModel.getInstance().setCurrentUser(null);
                Intent loginActivityIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginActivityIntent);
                finish();
            default:
                // Action not recognized
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        return PokeMapperModel.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null;
    }

    private void initialize() {
        if (!isUserLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to add `break;` after every case of switch statement.

**EDIT: YOU DONT NEED TO ADD `default:`, check the updated code.**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_marker:
                // User chose the "Add marker" item
                Intent addActivityIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(addActivityIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.action_logout:
                // User chose the "Uitloggen" item
                PokeMapperModel.getInstance().setCurrentUser(null);
                Intent loginActivityIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginActivityIntent);
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Tried it, then it says it's missing a return statement. Where do I fix that?

Comment: I dont understand why I always miss break statement !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return true;`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.one:
            one();
            return true;
        case R.id.two:
            two();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```